# ResponseStatusException is unauthorized, but ResponseEntity works perfectly fine

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security, endpoint

I've HTTP request redirect set up like that:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic(httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer -> httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                ).csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable()
                ).headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer.
                        frameOptions(frameOptionsConfig -> frameOptionsConfig.disable())
                ).authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/user").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()
                ).sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                );
        return http.build();
    }
```

Now, all other endpoints, besides the ones specified above, are restricted. The 401 code is thrown.
I have an endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/api/auth/user")
    public ResponseEntity createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) throws URISyntaxException {
        if (userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(user.getUsername()).isPresent()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            //return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        User createdUser = userRepository.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/auth/" + createdUser.getUsername()))
                .body(createdUser);
    }
```

Whenever someone provides User with an username already existing in the database, a "ResponseStatusException" is thrown because it's not good practice to allow having 2 same account with the very same username.
My question is, why do I get a 401 UNAUTHORIZED response when the if-block is executed and not the ResponseStatusException with its 409 CONFLICT?

Does the exception redirect me to another endpoint (if I allow "anyRequest" to be .permitAll(), then there's no issue)?
Below the exception is the commented line with ResponseEntity with 409 response. It works as I'd like it to: user is presented with 409 CONFLICT, but - out of curiosity - I want to know why the "ResponseStatusException" way does not work.

Comment: Did you enable your debug logs and read why?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Hi. I've noticed this:
`[io-28852-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}`
I suppose the ResponseStatusException redirects to "/error" endpoint?

Comment: I suggest you read the spring boot docs and especially the errorhandling chapter